# C# Run On Startup is added as disabled

Tags: c#, registry, startup

I am trying to add my application to StartUp, when I use my code to add an application to startup registry, it gets added but when I check in msconfig or taskmgr its disabled by default. Any idea how to fix this? Tested on Windows 8 and 8.1

```
   RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
   rk.SetValue("TestApp", Application.ExecutablePath);
   rk.Close();
```

Should I try to create a shortcut in shell:startup instead?
Thank you for help.